# having an infinite loop bug on this while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
empty_Carton = ''

print("Is the milk carton in the fridge empty? y/n")

input(empty_Carton)

while (empty_Carton != 'y') or (empty_Carton != 'n'):
    if empty_Carton == 'y':
        """Branch here"""
    elif empty_Carton == 'n':
        """Branch here"""
    else:
        print(empty_Carton + " is not a valid input. Type: 'y' or 'n'")
```

When I run this code it enters and infinite loop stuck on the 'else' condition when entering a correct 
input of 'y'

I tried moving the code around and changing the comparison operator but it still ends up in an infinite loop.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Also: in your own words, what do you expect `input(empty_Carton)` to do? Now, read the documentation and verify that.

Comment: Additionally the fact that `input()` is only called before the loop and not on each iteration means that it couldn't change anything even if it were otherwise used correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that `empty_Carton` never gets defined to be anything other than `""`, you can fix this with:

```py
empty_Carton = input("Is the milk carton in the fridge empty? y/n")
```

Note that the `input` function takes a string to print and returns the string entered by the user.

The next issue is that your `input` call is only made once (above the `while` loop), so the value of `empty_Carton` never gets updated and your loop runs forever. Really `empty_Carton`'s value should only get set at the top of the loop so that the loop will execute at least once, but will continue to execute until a valid value is entered.

Finally, since `empty_Carton` can never be both `'y'` and `'n'`, `empty_Carton` must always be not equal to at least one of those options, so your `while` condition is always `True`. You can fix this by replacing the `or` with an `and`, or with:

```py
while empty_Carton not in ('y', 'n'):
    # do stuff
```

Putting this all together, we get something like:

```py
empty_Carton = ''

while empty_Carton not in ('y', 'n'):
    empty_Carton = input("Is the milk carton in the fridge empty? y/n")
    if empty_Carton == 'y':
        print('y')
    elif empty_Carton == 'n':
        print('n')
```

Answer (score -1):

You have entered the input only once before while loop. Therefore it will run infinite times. Write a function instead and call that function in your `else` condition or just use a `break` statement.

```
empty_Carton = ""

print("Is the milk carton in the fridge empty? y/n") 

while (empty_Carton != 'y') or (empty_Carton != 'n'):
    if empty_Carton == 'y':
        """Branch here"""
    elif empty_Carton == 'n':
        """Branch here"""
    else:
        print(empty_Carton + " is not a valid input. Type: 'y' or 'n'")
        break
```